# PHP error with Responsive File Manager related to a specific directory

Tags: php

I am using the "plug-in" Responsive File Manager (http://www.responsivefilemanager.com).

There are numerous file/path settings in a config file, and write/modify permissions need to be set to a few folders. I believe I have all of that correct. However, this is the error I am getting:

> PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in
>   D:\genspangroup.com\wwwroot\models\filemanager\include\utils.php on
>   line 124

Line 124 of utils.php says:

```
mkdir($path_thumbs, 0777, true) or die("$path_thumbs cannot be found");
```

How can I know what the value of $path_thumbs is in this case? I tried adding an "echo $path_thumbs;" statement before this one, but that doesn't seem to do it.

If know the path it is trying to access, I can determine if this is a problem with permissions, or a problem with $path_thumbs not being set right.

Thanks!

Comment: does the echo output anything? If you echo "here" does it show

Comment: If the above is true, try `var_dump($path_thumbs);` as it might be a `NULL` value.

Comment: I put that before the mkdir statement above, but the error message just changes to Line 125. It doesn't display anything.

Comment: No, if I put echo "here"; before that line, I still don't see it. I'm not really that well versed with PHP, so not sure why! Thanks.

Comment: OK, I put a "die;" statement after my echo, just to see what is there, now I can see the value of that variable: ../filemanager-thumbs/

Answer (score 0):

The value is usually `../thumbs` but you can configure it in `config/config.php` in the file manager (line 32 in my version).

Additionally, if you turn on PHP errors (do this only in a test environment, not production), you will get the path as part of the error.